# An example calculated in Principles of Algebraic Geometry of Griffiths and Harris'.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

On page 413 they write:

> **Example.** We can now make a second computation for Chern classes of projective space. Let $X_0, \ldots , X_n$ be linear coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, and let $\mathfrak{E}$ and $\pi_*$ be as in the Euler sequence above. Let $A=(\alpha_{ij})$ be an $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix all of whose minors are distinct and nonzero, and consider the vector fields: $v_i = \mathfrak{E} (\alpha_{i0} X_0 , \ldots , \alpha_{in}X_n) = \pi_* \sum_j \alpha_{ij} X_i \frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}$.

They write that:

> ... we see that $v_1$ vanishes at $X\in \mathbb{P}^n$ exactly when $[\alpha_{10}X_0 , \ldots , \alpha_{1n}X_n] = [ X_0 , \ldots , X_n ] $

I do not understand how did they derive the last part, if we write the last identity then $v_1 = \pi_* \lambda \sum_j X_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, how do I see that $v_1$ vanishes from that identity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I guess the $\alpha_{ij}$ are just the $a_{ij}$ from the matrix $A$?

Comment: @JohnMartin yes, I'll edit my post. fixed it.

Comment: In case anyone didn't know, this textbook famously has many typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$I don't have access to the book, but the indexing appears to be off. (There should be $X_{j}$ instead of $X_{i}$ on the right side of $v_{i}$.) Assuming that's correct:

If $A = [\alpha_{ij}]$ is an invertible $(n + 1) \times (n + 1)$ complex matrix, $X = (X_{0}, \dots, X_{n})$ denotes Cartesian coordinates in $\Cpx^{n+1}$ and $\dd = (\frac{\dd}{\dd X_{0}}, \dots, \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{n}})$ denotes the Cartesian frame in $T\Cpx^{n+1}$, then
$$
V_{i} := \sum_{j=0}^{n} \alpha_{ij}X_{j} \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{j}}
$$
defines a frame in $T\Cpx^{n+1}$ whose elements descend to $\Cpx\Proj^{n}$. Specifically, if $\pi:\Cpx^{n+1}\setminus\{0\} \to \Cpx\Proj^{n}$ denotes the projection, then the image $v_{i} := \pi_{*}(X)(V_{i})$ is independent of the representative $X$. For example, in the affine chart $\{X_{0} \neq 0\}$, we have $\pi(X) = \frac{1}{X_{0}}(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})$, and a short calculation shows
$$
\pi_{*}(tX)(tV_{i}) = \pi_{*}(X)(V_{i})\quad\text{for all $t$ in $\Cpx^{\times}$.}
$$

Now, $\ker\pi_{*}(X)$ is spanned by the value of the "tautological vector field" $\sum X_{j} \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{j}}$ at $X$, precisely because $\pi$ sends each line through the origin to a point of $\Cpx\Proj^{n}$. Consequently, if $V_{i}$ is proportional to the tautological field along some line through the origin, then $v_{i} = 0$ at the corresponding point $[X]$ of $\Cpx\Proj^{n}$.

Comment: How does $\pi_*(X)(V_i)$ look like?

Comment: If $n = 1$ and
$A = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
    4 &  5 \\
    3 & -2 \\
  \end{array}\right]$, for example, then
\begin{align*}
  V_{1} &= 4X_{0}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{0}} + 5X_{1}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{1}}, \\
  V_{2} &= 3X_{0}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{0}} - 2X_{1}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd X_{1}}.
\end{align*}
Letting $x = \pi(X_{0}, X_{1}) = X_{1}/X_{0}$ denote the affine coordinate, $d\pi(X) = -\frac{X_{1}}{X_{0}^{2}}\,dX_{0} + \frac{1}{X_{0}}\, dX_{1}$, so
\begin{align*}
  v_{1} &= (-4 + 5)x\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}, \\
  v_{2} &= (-3 - 2)x\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Andrew, how did you get $v_1,v_2$?, I am missing the explicit calculation.

Comment: Plug $V_{i}$ into $d\pi(X)$ using $dX_{i}(\dd/\dd X_{j}) = \delta_{ij}$, $x = X_{1}/X_{0}$, and interpreting the resulting scalar function as the coefficient of $\dd/\dd x$. :)

Comment: OK, thanks. As everything in math it's easy when you understand the details behind it.

Comment: Just one more question, when I operate $dX_i \partial X_k/ \partial X_j = dX_i \delta_{kj}$, how is this reconciled with what you wrote? I don't understnad this part I mean this field $dX_i \partial/ \partial X_j $ should operate on some variable, shouldn't it?

Comment: Actually not: The coordinate one-form $dX_{i}$ operates on the coordinate vector field $\dd/\dd X_{j}$ by$$dX_{i}\left(\frac{\dd}{\dd X_{j}}\right) = \frac{\dd X_{i}}{\dd X_{j}} = \delta_{ij}$$(a scalar). In words, one can (and as a geometer, does :) view tangent vectors as differential operators, one-forms as functions on tangent vectors, and the chain rule as a geometric assertion about mappings between tangent bundles.

Comment: Ok , I see now. If I'll keep reading books from geometry and PDE theory I am bound to get confused over this. :-D